# Can receive mail directly from mail server in custom iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm going to write custom app in iPhone similar Mail app build-in iOS.
This app can get mail directly from Gmail and sent mail with
attachment, forwarding, reply all, etc.

I can do that? And Apple support API for development?

I try googling and all result I found: Just can send mail, and haven't
get mail directly from any mail server? Please help me :)

Thanks in advance.

--
Phu Nguyen

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [skpsmtpmessage](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) library. I will help you to send mails directly from iOS devices.

Edit:

Look at this [connect to gmail database to read/write emails](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?tid=19b7e5fa1a089628&hl=en).

I think that you should focus more on [google api](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/) then on the iOS implementation.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know another library to support receive mail from Gmail?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on this kind of app. What if I give you a complete app URL for free hmmm? here you go buddy have fun.

[Gmail in custom native iphone app](http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/)