# Fetch and Send email in iPad app programmatically

Tags: ios

What I want is to allow user to send and receive mail from my iPad app. I know that I can user MFMAilComposer but it's for sending only as per my requirement I need to provide all functionaly of an iPad email client app.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can send email using your iPhone app either using background or using the POP3/SMTP see the following link. 
[Open Source Cocoa/Cocoa-Touch POP3/SMTP library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740939/open-source-cocoa-cocoa-touch-pop3-smtp-library)

However,  You can not get the emails received in iPhone mail box.  But I think you can receive email from your mail server...See this stack overflow link you will get more idea [Can receive mail directly from mail server in custom iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353942/can-receive-mail-directly-from-mail-server-in-custom-iphone-app)

Hope my answer helps..